# Why it is better to have two legs than four?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, everyday-life, structural-beam

I cite from the available on internet book "Structures or why things don't fall down" written by J.E.Gordon.

...**from the structural point of view two legs are better than four, and the centripede is perheps only saved from total inadequacy by the fact that its legs are two short**

Does anybody understand this statement?

Comment: Simple extrapolation would suggest that if 2 legs were better than 4, that 1 leg would be even better, and zero legs would be best (well, sounds like -1 leg would be pretty good too).

Comment: He is considering legs as supporting poles for a mass. He is claiming that the total weight of these poles, increases with the number of poles (not linearly). An efficient structural design would therefore reduce the number of poles along with their parasitic weight. The centripede with tens of legs, is wasting energy to carry the extra weight associated with those legs. The very short legs of the centripede are an advantage reducing weight.

Comment: what kind of chair do you usually sit on?

Comment: 2 important factors to consider are the ability for the object to balance and the efficiency.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero mine has 5 legs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the optimum number of legs depends on the design objective of the leg and the thing to which it is attached. Is the objective of the leg to simply support mass, or to facilitate movement? Does that movement have to be rapid or can it be slow? In which directions must that movement occur? Are there other things that the leg in question has to do besides move?

While in the Galapagos some years ago I tried to play tag on a sandy beach with a small ghost crab. Like most crabs it had two pincers and four more legs on each side and when at rest or moving slowly, it used all 8 of those legs. But above a certain speed, it retracted two of the legs on each side and ran with blinding speed on a total of four legs. It transitioned back to eight legs upon slowing down.

In the water, it used its legs to swim, and as I recall the hindmost pair were slightly flattened into paddle-like structures that performed the bulk of the swimming work.

So- what's the right answer? It depends on the mission!